# ActionScript 3 Sprite Envelope

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, sprite, effects

I'm quite new to Flash and ActionScript.
Anyway, I wrote my own XML Slideshow, that's working great. The problem I have is that I can't add an 'envelope' effect to the images that are loaded as sprites. I know I can use 'envelope tool' if I break the image apart (ctrl+b) but I need to do it dynamically via AS.
Is there any way to do it.

Rotating the X/Y/Z axis doesn't do what I need.

Looking forward to your replies.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically let's u move around each individual corner

Comment: I still have no idea what you are talking about, link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/distort-movieclip-or-image-in-flash-with-as3?

I think this can help you a lot.

Comment: nope, haven't seen it. Will try it right now. Thanks! Looks very promising )

Comment: Hey it really looks awesome, tried the demo. The thing is that I am loading the images from an XML file so they are of a Loader class adn I get this errror: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Loader@29130061 to flash.display.MovieClip.

Comment: So, create a movieclip and add this loader as a child of it and transform this mc instead.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I have a main MC container - slideshow and a child MC - slide. I load all the images into the slide container. Am I supposed to transform slide like so - var distortClip:DistortImageWrapper = new DistortImageWrapper(slide);

Comment: GREAT! got it working, sorry for so many comments, works perfectly! Thanks a million!